# Longest Repeating Subsequence of a Single Digit

Tags: code-golf, number, integer, counting, subsequence

### Challenge:

Given a positive integer, output the longest single-digit subsequence that occurs at least twice, AND has boundaries of another digit (or the start/end of the integer).

**An example:**

Input: `7888885466662716666`
The longest subsequence of a single digit would be `88888` (`7[88888]5466662716666`) with a length of 5. However, this subsequence only occurs once in the integer.
Instead, the result for input `7888885466662716666` should be `6666` (`78888854[6666]271[6666]`), since it occurs (at least) twice.

### Challenge rules:

- Length of the subsequences takes priority over the amount of times it occurs. (I.e. with input `8888858888866656665666`, we output `88888` (`[88888]5[88888]66656665666`; length 5, occurs twice), and not `666` (`88888588888[666]5[666]5[666]`; length 3, occurs thrice).
- If the length of multiple subsequences are equal, we output the one with the largest occurrence-count. I.e. with input `3331113331119111`, we output `111` (`333[111]333[111]9[111]`; length 3, occurs thrice), and not `333` (`[333]111[333]1119111`; length 3 as well, but occurs twice)
- If the occurrence-count and length of multiple subsequences are equal, you can output either of them, or all (in any order). I.e. with input `777333777333`, the possible outputs are: `777`; `333`; `[777, 333]`; or `[333, 777]`.
- The subsequence must have boundaries of other digits (or the start/end of the integer). I.e. with input `122222233433` the result is `33` (`1222222[33]4[33]`; length 2, occurs twice) and not `222` (`1[222][222]33433`, length 3, occurs twice with both invalid).

  - This applies to all numbers that are counted towards the occurrence-counter. I.e. with input `811774177781382` the result is `8` (`[8]117741777[8]13[8]2`; length 1, occurs thrice) and not `77` (`811[77]41[77]781382` / `811[77]417[77]81382`; length 2, occurs twice with one invalid) nor `1` (`8[1][1]774[1]7778[1]382`; length 1, occurs four times with two invalid).
- You can assume the input won't contain any digits `0` (it will match `[1-9]+`). (This is to avoid having to deal with test cases like `10002000` that should output `000`, where most languages would output `0` by default.)
- You can assume the input will always contain at least one valid output.
- I/O are both flexible. Can be a list/array/stream of digits/bytes/characters or as string instead of a single integer.

### General rules:

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins.
  Don't let code-golf languages discourage you from posting answers with non-codegolfing languages. Try to come up with an as short as possible answer for 'any' programming language.
- [Standard rules apply](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet/2422#2422) for your answer, so you are allowed to use STDIN/STDOUT, functions/method with the proper parameters and return-type, full programs. Your call.
- [Default Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- If possible, please add a link with a test for your code.
- Also, adding an explanation for your answer is highly recommended.

### Test cases:

```
Input:  7888885466662716666 / [7,8,8,8,8,8,5,4,6,6,6,6,2,7,1,6,6,6,6]
Output: 6666                / [6,6,6,6]

Input:  3331113331119111 / [3,3,3,1,1,1,3,3,3,1,1,1,9,1,1,1]
Output: 111              / [1,1,1]

Input:            777333777333                   / [7,7,7,3,3,3,7,7,7,3,3,3]
Possible outputs: 777; 333; [777,333]; [333;777] / [7,7,7]; [3,3,3]; [[7,7,7],[3,3,3]]; [[3,3,3],[7,7,7]]

Input:  122222233433 / [1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,3,3]
Output: 33           / [3,3]

Input:  811774177781382 / [8,1,1,7,7,4,1,7,7,7,8,1,3,8,2] 
Output: 8               / [8]

Input:  555153333551 / [5,5,5,1,5,3,3,3,3,5,5,1] 
Output: 1            / [1]

Input:            12321              / [1,2,3,2,1]
Possible outputs: 1; 2; [1,2]; [2,1] / [1]; [2]; [[1],[2]]; [[2],[1]]

Input:  944949949494999494 / [9,4,4,9,4,9,9,4,9,4,9,4,9,9,9,4,9,4]
Output: 4                  / [4]

Input:  8888858888866656665666 / [8,8,8,8,8,5,8,8,8,8,8,6,6,6,5,6,6,6,5,6,6,6]
Output: 88888                  / [8,8,8,8,8]

Input:  1112221112221111               / [1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,1]
Output: 111; 222; [111,222]; [222,111] / [1,1,1]; [2,2,2]; [[1,1,1],[2,2,2]]; [[2,2,2],[1,1,1]]

Input:  911133111339339339339339 / [9,1,1,1,3,3,1,1,1,3,3,9,3,3,9,3,3,9,3,3,9,3,3,9]
Output: 111                      / [1,1,1]
```

Comment: Suggested test case: `8888858888866656665666`. If I interpreted the challenge correctly, both the Brachylog and 05AB1E solutions fail.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Added, thanks.

Comment: @Arnauld Hmm, it would be one of the winners anyway in my opinion because it occurs as many times as `222` when bounded by other integers. I guess we just shouldn't count the occurrence that is a substring of `1111`. Better wait for the OP though, indeed.

Comment: @Arnauld For `1112221112221111` these are the subsequences and their counts: `1111 (1)`, `111 (2)`, `222 (2)`. Since we only outputs sequences occurring at least twice, the output can be one of: `111`, `222`, `[111,222]`, `[222,111]`. (See the fourth rule for some more information.) Basically `1111` will only ever count as `1111`, and not as `1` and `111` or `11` and `11`. I'll add your test case, but the output is either or both of `111` and `222`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `o`, 68 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 8.5 bytes

```
Ġ:UÞ⊍⁽LO∆M
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyJvQT0iLCIiLCLEoDpVw57iio3igb1MT+KIhk0iLCIiLCI1NTUxNTMzMzM1NTFcbjc4ODg4ODU0NjY2NjI3MTY2NjZcbjg4ODg4NTg4ODg4NjY2NTY2NjU2NjZcbjMzMzExMTMzMzExMTkxMTEiXQ==)

groups by identical adjacent digits, finds the duplicated elements, then takes the most common of the longest runs.

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 14 bytes

```
γÐ¢1›ÏD€gZQÏ.M
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LU0xCgJBEOvnLSJkZ8bZ7W0tbO1OELGyEATBQvzA@QZrOzvL295H3EfWuV0TkhAI5HjqtodduZ4v5fvOj@GJ8fbJ/XK8v/abde7nqzIrFieoLBzBMAUxM4DmyUVm5q05IVQwi5cImInLIjgGUlWor9jTlxxASSRJSlJZk9pndf/Tv34)

**Explanation**

```
γ                # group consecutive equal elements
 Ð¢              # count the occurrence of each group among the list of groups
   1›Ï           # keep only groups with a count greater than 1
      D€gZQÏ     # keep only those with a length equal to the greatest length
            .M   # get the most common item
```

Comment: @Riley: Unfortunately that would get the first element which is not necessarily the most common one.

Comment: Oops.. I missed that bullet.

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 bytes

```
Œgœ-Q$LÐṀÆṃ'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opPSjk3UDVXwOT3i4s@Fw28Odzer/D7c/alqTBcSPGuZYP2qY6/7/f3S0uY4FHJrqmOiYQaGRjrmOIYwXq8MVbawDgoZgiMy2hNAgJeY6IAiRRGKDpAyBBiIgSNgEJmUBNgCk2gRKg9wEssRCxwikwFQHBA2B2BgKwXyYscZADOZYAg0w0bEEY0s4C8KDsiH2IfyLYEN8aopKx8YCAA)

#### Previous version – 14 bytes

```
ŒgŒQ¬TịƲLÐṀÆṃ'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opPSjkwIPrQl5uLv72CafwxMe7mw43PZwZ7P6/8Ptj5rWZAHxo4a51u7//0dHm@tYwKGpjomOGRQa6ZjrGMJ4sTpc0cY6IGgIhshsSwgNUmKuA4IQSSQ2SMoQaCACgoRNYFIWYANAqk2gNMhNIEssdIxACkx1QNAQiI2hEMyHGWsMxGCOJdAAEx1LMLaEsyA8KDs2FgA)

#### How it works?

```
Œgœ-Q$LÐṀÆṃ' – Full program. Receives a list of digits as input.
Œg           – Group equal adjacent values.
  œ-Q$       – Multiset difference with itself deduplicate.
      LÐṀ    – Keep those that are maximal by length.
         Æṃ' – Mode. Returns the most common element(s).
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
ŒgŒQ¬TịƲLÐṀÆṃ' – Full program. Receives a list of digits as input.
Œg             – Group equal adjacent values.
  ŒQ           – Distinct sieve. Replace the first occurrences of each value by 1.
                 and the rest by 0. [1,2,3,2,3,2,5]ŒQ -> [1,1,1,0,0,0,1]       
    ¬T         – Negate and find the truthy indices.
      ịƲ       – Then index in the initial list of groups.
               – This discards the groups that only occur once.
        LÐṀ    – Find all those which are maximal by length.
           Æṃ' – And take the mode.
```

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>79</s> <s>73</s> 68 bytes

Takes input as a string. Returns an integer.

```javascript
s=>[...s,r=q=0].map(o=d=>q=s^d?o[!o[q]|r[q.length]?q:r=q]=s=d:q+d)|r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVHbboMwDH3fV7CngsbSOZcFitJ@CMqkqtB2EyMNqfbUf2dO6CoUZmQ7Cec4x/HX/mfvDsPn5fram6Ydj2p0alsTQlw@KKveNPneX1KjGrW1yn00O1M/m9rq21Bb0rX96XrWO7tBrFZONRv70mS3YTyY3pmuJZ05pcd0JQtvgr@jUQk@rbIs8bZeJ377FDEYYwAwxRL9Dz4x8CAmSCkRPcUZ@E7A8yrBP1VS4zLHlY4LAA3GGP@vAGMxvgCQkqPLAlhB5xTEFzFcCAEC72WYl@VhqYbRGDeDVwnFViCnizZKzkteljx8IT@qIJEvugiDCRGnIO4eKL4Lbwtp4J/qEZejQXE0yAMUSKkefwE)

#### Commented

```javascript
s =>                      // s = input string, also used as the current digit
  [ ...s,                 // split s into a list of digit characters
    r =                   // r is the final result
    q =                   // q is the current digit sequence
    0                     // append a final dummy entry to force the processing of the last
  ]                       // sequence
  .map(o =                // o is an object used to keep track of encountered sequences
       d =>               // for each digit d in the array defined above:
    q =                   //   update q:
      s ^ d ?             //     if d is not equal to the current digit:
        o[                //       this statement will ultimately update o[q]
          !o[q] |         //         if q has not been previously seen
          r[q.length] ?   //         or the best result is longer than q:
            q             //           leave r unchanged
          :               //         else:
            r = q         //           set r to q
        ] = s = d         //       reset q to d, set the current digit to d
                          //       and mark q as encountered by setting o[q]
      :                   //     else:
        q + d             //       append d to q
  ) | r                   // end of map(); return r, coerced to an integer
```

Comment: Maybe I'm saying something incorrect here, but since `...s` converts the input to a list of digit characters, isn't it shorter to just take the input as a list of digit characters to begin with, instead of a string? I've allowed flexible I/O. (But I'm assuming it interferes with another part of your code?)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen The problem is that I need an extra iteration to process the last sequence. So I'd need to do `[...s,0]` even if `s` already is a list.

Answer (score 4):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 56 bytes

```
L`(.)\1*
O`
L$m`^(.+)(¶\1)+$
$#2;$1
N`
.+;

N$`
$.&
-1G`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYtBDsIwDATv/gYBpVRE2tjBifoALlX5QIXCgQOHckC8jQfwseK2Y@2uVlq/H5/n64557y917qsPzYgjXSv1bqo3H9rG/74jmtaR28XOgYZKoe2IBlfJhQOdYJ@z5oUkZyMqliBmBrB5MZGqWtucEFeYxUoGVMWkGZwjpZSQbMWWtuQIKiJFSpH11vwD) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
L`(.)\1*
```

List all the maximally repeated digit subsequences.

```
O`
```

Sort the list into order.

```
L$m`^(.+)(¶\1)+$
$#2;$1
```

List all the multiple subsequences with their "count".

```
N`
```

Sort in ascending order of count.

```
.+;
```

Delete the counts.

```
N$`
$.&
```

Sort in ascending order of length. (Where lengths are equal, the previous order due to count is preserved.)

```
-1G`
```

Keep the last i.e. longest value.

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>58</s> 56 bytes

```perl6
*.comb(/(.)$0*/).Bag.max({.value>1,+.key.comb,.{*}}).key
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU1BDoIwELzvK3owhiIpLm0pDcrBj5hqwIMQDEYjIby9LsU4m5nJJJOdRz20ue9Gtm3Y0cfi2neXKI0E3@zjlIuTu4nOfaJJvF37qitMduJej6GWiCmeZ75kX8LTjayJNmfOmn5gBzDFAq1yQmZwMZBSIuKqlgjGGEqrAmYBUioKBaIximgKlEUGWmvU1JLk1JQZglXKKmtVuOCwbgalPf0j0BQ9/itCVfov)

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 102 bytes

```r
function(i)rep(names(sort(-(x=(x=table(rle(i)))[rowSums(x>1)>0,,drop=F])[m<-max(rownames(x)),])[1]),m)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVDNbsMgDL7nKSJORiJSHWAEqe1xL7Bj1UPWpRJS/gREy54@MzBNNfgz/sA/2B/P@twcz21@RLfM4LgfVpj7aQgQFh@hgf1CO/af4wCe1HHOb375/timAPsV@fUkxJdf1sv7nd@mczP1O9B9ybFzLojGOxcTP@IQYqB69QMqZrokWr2RtAaTYaJiUkpELGhJE2eMIaJg8rHNIqUqfodojCI1HcquTZTWGjU9l2RLiGzzwSpllbUqr2xzhtxLRupD/2kOxFTtH0uO3GEG@7oZr6rQr@v4A/mron4ZbP2EbR5diBCiD@voIjhRM0bz5Mcv)

Since there wasn't an R answer yet, I decided to give it a try, and well... it wasn't easy. I don't really know whether it is a good approach, but here it goes.

Inputs and outputs vectors of characters.

Comment: Close to 100 bytes is pretty good for R with this challenge.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>123</s> 120 bytes

```python
import re
def f(s):r=re.findall(r'(\d)(\1*)',s);c=r.count;print max((len(a+b)*(c((a,b))>1),c((a,b)),a+b)for a,b in r)[2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY3RbsMgDEXf8xVIe4jpokoGMqCo@5F1D2kS1EgpiWgqbV@fGeiM7HvNMWb93W5LEPs@3dclbiyO1TB65uHBT/Ecx6OfwtDNM8QaLgOHCx543Ty468/x2C/PsLk1TmFj9@4HYB4DdO9XfoAeoGuunH8ib/59k5BfIqOOTYFF/iW@dw@1Nila9UEhNCapefXGkqkqGpBSImKpljJT0gy11kRKTYCcY@RdpihySKkKJZLvDaLWilIblEZkZDJp2xZbei9Jy0evRVK8esdEWW6VsspalU/WPKD2Pw)

Answer (score 3):

## Powershell, 101 byte

```
($args|sls '(.)\1*'-a|%{$_.Matches}|group|?{$_.Count-1}|sort @{e={$_.Name.Length,$_.Count}})[-1].Name
```

Explanied test script:

```
$f = {

(
    $args|          # for each argument (stings)
    sls '(.)\1*'-a| # searches all
    %{$_.Matches}|  # regex matches
    group|          # group it (Note: Count of each group > 0 by design)
    ?{$_.Count-1}|  # passthru groups with Count not equal 1
    sort @{         # sort all groups by 2 values
        e={$_.Name.Length,$_.Count}
    }
)[-1].Name          # returns name of last group (group with max values)

}

@(
    ,('7888885466662716666', '6666')
    ,('3331113331119111', '111')
    ,('777333777333', '777','333')
    ,('122222233433', '33')
    ,('811774177781382', '8')
    ,('555153333551','1')
    ,('12321', '1','2')
    ,('944949949494999494','4')
    ,('8888858888866656665666','88888')
    ,('1112221112221111','111','222')
) | % {
    $s,$e = $_
    $r = &$f $s
    "$($r-in$e): $r"
}
```

Output:

```
True: 6666
True: 111
True: 777
True: 33
True: 8
True: 1
True: 1
True: 4
True: 88888
True: 111
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>114</s> 113 bytes

-1 byte thanks to [TFeld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/38592/tfeld).

```python
p='';r=[];C=r.count
for c in input():r+=['']*(c!=p);r[-1]+=c;p=c
print max((len(w),C(w),w)for w in r if~-C(w))[2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU49T8MwEN39K0wWJ5Qi@QsnjTxVZWVhizIU46oRJbFOjtIu/PXgcxF3vvf8TvcVbvE8jWJ106e3RVGswTLWgu36dm/h2U3zGMlpAuroMKYX5lhWO9jYjrH@sXQPNlQtdFveb6xrg3UkwDBG@n28luXFj@VSPe0RlgqnLDgF6HD62WK26kS/pq2ELOfh4uk7zH5HKI1wQ6LUX72jeBvBv/Mh0sPb6wFggnvBB/jj18pMjabVSzJhOBIjTErJOb9jkyKljDFJ3zFJLrJJqbKsOTdGpTA1l7VIGa0116lWJs71UiA3SjWqaVT2zNidb8iY9uu/wC6Oe/6Rs18)

Answer (score 3):

### Haskell, 72 bytes

```
import Data.Lists
g!x|y<-countElem x g=(y>1,1<$x,y)
(argmax=<<(!)).group
```

How it works

```
(argmax=<<(!)).group       -- expands to: f i = argmax (group i !) (group i)
    group                  -- split the input list into subsequences of equal digits
                           -- e.g. "1112211" -> ["111","22","11"]

                           -- find the element of this list where the function !
                           -- returns the maximum value. First parameter to !
                           -- is the grouped input list, second parameter the
                           -- the element to look at 

g!x|
    y<-countElem x g       -- let y be the number of occurrences of x in g
  = (  ,   ,  )            -- return a triple of
     y>1                   -- a boolean y>1  (remember: True > False)  
        1<$x               -- length of x (to be exact: all elements in x
                           -- replaced by 1. This sorts the same way as the
                           -- length of x)
             y             -- y
                           -- a triples sorts lexicographical
```

Comment: Do you not need to use *Haskell + lists* as language because Data.Lists is not part of base?

Comment: @BWO: don't know. I've always used a plain "Haskell", even when I imported an exotic library (e.g. `Gloss` for graphical output or `Matrix`). I use "Haskell + something" if I don't want to include the byte count for the imports. I think we had this topic on meta, but I cannot find it anymore. If I remember correctly, we had no general definition of "standard library".  What should be the reference for Haskell? The Haskell Report, GHC's base, Haskell Plattform, something else?

Comment: IMO it should be as with C/JavaScript/.. that (if it matters) we need to use *Haskell (GHC)* or *Haskell (Hugs)* etc. because the implementation specifies a language on PPCG. So for a *GHC* answer that would include base and for all the other ones I wouldn't know :D

Comment: Do you perhaps have a TIO link so it can be tested? Or is the `Data.Lists` library not available on TIO or another online Haskell compiler?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen: yes `Data.Lists` is missing on TIO. You can test it with [this version](https://tio.run/##TU7BboMwDL3zFS7qASRaySQsIEFP221/sO4QdYGiJYAglai0bx9zAt1m4ufkGT@/q5w@ldZLa4Z@tPAsrTy@tpMNLv2tsy9aGVAaNDFQgVZdY6@wh7rVVo0QVZXSse8GcmyMnKF@/Fv3@kMjRGcSOJygraml4ERowF5VRw@lJwVmm6@r8xKtIlVZRrs4PjZjfxuCZjd/3cvDn58Zmiq6nzDBcj8n93gxsu1o4zC2nSVzRg605S0ACEXuIuNPFKlAV8LENRhjiLhiQbmyQgiiVgwTcBSmPhjjjnJMjigEpxQ5sjxdySzLMKMpRnVlMGXpdi04L3hRcP/5uil5cx7JWLblNo5u8y8@lLxpD8X/E74v35day2ZaDpdh@AE "Haskell – Try It Online").

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 85 bytes

```r
function(x,R=rle(x),a=ave(R$v,R,FUN=length))rep(R$v[o<-order(a<2,-R$l,-a)[1]],R$l[o])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVE9b8MgEN3zK5CTASQyHOBiS/HasYOlTlEGq8GOJcdEhETpr3cP7DYfTfvw3Rl4evd0uKEuhvrUf/jW9vTCy8J1hl4Yr4rqbGi5OPOSv76/FZ3pG79jzJlDOF3b1dK6rXG0Wgm@LBcdX1ZsDZsNx/@13bChKa66rKZH77xt6anv2qMPu@Ohaz22JEnCELNZQxOdBaTqBSE0hJIwMmFOwj7QpJQAMOYc48qJNDyJYlojZcx3jJFlWr8zjuA9qfotQRLhxDpi@@4TkyG2JsjYBykQEVKqp1JSBlIGoLXC0BnITNzz5iQLnDRNIcVWEusTIRibSfH78tE3RNfiT8u5UrnKcxVXrDeSc6Ki4zjtmHGy6RQTDx0HREcQBvCTH@f97QgmT@IfV/HdYspvv6g4vtxs@AI)

- **Input :** a vector of separated integer digits e.g. `c(1,8,8...)`
- **Output :** a vector of separated integer digits

Unrolled code with explanation :

```r
function(x){                # x is a vector of digits : e.g. c(1,1,8,8,1,1)

R = rle(x)                  # Get the sequences of consecutive repeating digits
                            # doing run length encoding on x, i.e. : R is a list
                            # with the digits (R$values) and the number of their
                            # consecutive occurrencies (R$lengths)
                            # N.B. you can use R$v for R$values and R$l for R$lenghts

a=ave(R$v,R,FUN=length)     # Group R$v by R$l AND R$v, count the occurrencies 
                            # for each group and "unroll" the value of each 
                            # group to the original R$v length.
                            # Here basically we count the occurrencies of the same 
                            # sequence.

o<-order(a<2,-R$l,-a)[1]    # Get the indexes used to order by a < 2 then by -R$l and
                            # finally by -a; store the first index in "o".
                            # Here basically we use order to select the first sequence 
                            # repeated at least twice, in case of ties the sequence 
                            # with the greatest length and in case of ties the most 
                            # repeated sequence.

rep(R$v[o],R$v[o])          # Using the index "o", we reconstruct the sequence repeating
                            # R$l[o] times R$v[o]
}
```

---

Alternative version accepting vector of integer or character digits :

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 88 bytes

```r
function(x,R=rle(x),a=ave(R$v,R,FUN=length))rep(R$v[o<-tail(order(a>1,R$l,a),1)],R$l[o])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZE9b4MwEIZ3foVFMtiSOxw2NUilY8cOSJ2iDKgxCZKLI@NE6a@nZ0Obj6Y98B3Yj957dXZjW43toX/3ne3pideVM5qeGG@q5qhpvTzymr@8vVZG91u/Y8zpfdhd2acH33SGWrfRjjbPwOul4Q3jwNbhc2XXbNxWZ2nW0kNvusHTwbthbzqP7UiaMsaSZEtTVYTI5SNGpiCUlJE5FiT8B0wIAQBTLnGdmYjhThRTCpEpXxETpTu/047gOWn6DUGIcGIdsb35xKSJbQkSH0EKshhCyLtSQgSoAFBK4lIFiCK75hakCEye55BjK4H1jhBMzUT2@/DWN0TX2Z@WSylLWZYyPrFeSC6IjI7jtGPGyebzmjl0HCI6gjCAn3w7729HMHvK/nEV7y2m8vKNitPNJeMX)

- **Input :** a vector of separated characters or digits e.g. `c("1","8","8"...)` or `c(1,8,8...)`
- **Output :** a vector of separated characters if the input was a vector of characters, a vector of digits if the input was a vector of digits

Comment: Can you add an explanation? I don't understand how it's working.

Comment: @JayCe: done! (I've added details that you well know, just for non-R users ;) )

Comment: ty! It makes sense now.

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 67 bytes

```
#&@@@MaximalBy[Select[Tally@Split@#,Last@#>1&],{Length@#,#2}&@@#&]&
```

Pure function. Takes a list of digits as input and returns a list of subsequences (in no particular order) as output. Not sure if the "must appear at least twice" clause can be handled more cleanly. 
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVJNS8QwEL33VwwbCAoD2o/YrUUJnlcQ1lvpISxZt5AuYnNwKf3tNSQkplW2PNLp65uZN0N6oU@yF7o7iHk@whPcEMo5fxXfXS/Uy6XZSyUPunkXSl34/lN1mhPcicG8nlPa4riT5w99MiTJJpNKaEtv61nLQQ@m3DiWCNslGEKB8BAhQzCyNCYnTMA8Y47gkHr8ZaoQ@6zSFiwj8ZrxytR2X8FpiqVy67u4OkUUuxmdNxNkPoXZYZn9xSIzeeCXNnJ7BrKyXQo7oDur5Wcgf5nI7WrnKyasmv0bR8YcwnKuMPE49x5ZiKepTpK3r@6sG4KweYQNwrEhbQsU7jjYO1PPPw)

Comment: Could you perhaps add a TIO link for it?

Comment: If you really insist...

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>68</s> 67 bytes

```ruby
->a{(b=a.chunk &:+@).max_by{|x|[(c=b.count x)<2?0:x[1].size,c]}[1]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVDbCsIwDH3fV4w9iKIW04tdxan/MYZ0RVHEC7rBdPPbZ5qKmDbnJIcmTXuvy2e/z/rpyrbDMrPMHerLKR4sxpsRO9tmWz7brunyoctK5q71pYqb0ZKvZ4smh4I9jq/dxBVvjN99HiU69abkHI1r8JRMokQIAQABDbrXtNYoBPQ5cDIhZMhTAK0luk5BpNxLSilQeFwghxLBKTBSGmmMpEVMHWgWQpxDfZ0Kwd/2w9CDJiQw/zuJCraz7tB2VXeL93mFX2TvD3zvBw)

Inputs and outputs arrays of chars.

The approach is pretty straightforward: we identify the runs of consecutive digits (`chunk` using unary `+` as identity function) and take the maximum - first by the size of the run (reset to zero if its occurrence count is < 2), then by the count itself.

Answer (score 2):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), <strike>256</strike> 250 bytes

```
func[s][p: func[b][sort parse b[collect[any keep[copy a skip thru any a]]]]first
last sort/compare collect[foreach d p p s[if 1 < k: length? to-block d[keep/only
reduce[form unique d k]]]]func[x y][(reduce[length? x/1 x/2])< reduce[length? y/1 y/2]]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY/PboQgEMbvPsVkT@2h2SBYdLNJ36FXwsFF7BpdoYDJ@vR2YP@E7eB8I/Ppj8HpbvvWnZBFf9j6ZVbCS2EPkF5PUnjjAtjWeQ0nocw0aRVEO68wam2xYVdowY@DhXB2C0SnlRj94HwoptYHiIi9MhekaHggeuN0q87QgcXlxdADgSOMB5j0/BPOXxDMx2kyaoROxLP2Zp7WwuluUTr@fYFlHn4XjYQxHRgHvsIqxdv9owfouieYpXw/wj9nRWdFR8rNumEO0MOO1zEq9olRchLLrni6lFJCyE0bzMzinGP/plmblCkoZS/tmhDOGSavCa3LzKmqilTIoFhfOLTM9w1jDWsallaqOT3dISnOX90zp5E411NfwOmCSZr82W1/)

Really, realy long solution this time... (sigh)

Takes the input as a string.

### Explanation:

```
f: func [ s ] [
    p: func [ b ] [                        ; groups and sorts the adjacent repeating items
        sort parse b [ 
            collect [                      
                any keep[
                    copy a skip thru any a ; gather any item, optionally followed by itself  
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
    t: copy []
    foreach d p p s [                     ; p p s transforms the input string into a block of sorted blocks of repeating digits
        if 1 < k: length? to-block d [    ; filters only the blocks that occur more than once
            insert/only t reduce [ form unique d k ] ; stores the digits and the number of occurences
                                          ; "8888858888866656665666" -> [["5" 3] ["666" 3] ["88888" 2]]
        ]
    ]
    first last sort/compare t func [ x y ] ; takes the first element (the digits) of the last block of the sorted block of items
        [ (reduce [ length? x/1 x/2 ]) < reduce [ length? y/1 y/2 ] ] ; direct comparison of the blocks
]
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Java (JDK 10)](http://jdk.java.net/), 213 bytes

```java
s->{int l=99,X[][]=new int[10][l],d,D=0,m=0,M=0;for(var x:s.split("(?<=(.))(?!\\1)"))X[x.charAt(0)-48][x.length()]++;for(;M<1&&l-->1;)for(d=0;d++<9;)if((m=X[d][l])>1&m>M){M=m;D=d;}for(;l-->0;)System.out.print(D);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVFNb6MwEL3nV8wiJbIbQuMAC8Qh1WpzzamXSJQDy0dKli9hJ9sq4rdnbZMm7LaGmZHf8zzGj0N0imaH5PclL5u65XAQe@PI88J4oKNPWHasYp7XlSTjImIMtlFewXkE0Bx/FXkMjEdclFOdJ1AKDj3zNq/2QQhRu2dYHQX4WVfsWKbtqmfXkIF/YbP1Oa84FL7n6bsgDEK/Sv@AgAIyD4Mi1BN948/1UsTWn9OsbtEpauFtyQzWFDlHGnpa@cjAGD19e3khWMN4F7wZ8WvU/uBojmeWG4p9kVZ7/opwOJ0qEbpdkcmkmM3WhGIJJEI9mU5XHsV5hlDp74JEDoDXZFKut/i89Uu68RPaqXbZOaf4@Z3xtDTqIzcacSuONph2F6oufHOBp4wz8K8@AGiOK5dtfRdr4RBZNP2DNE2TENJnT8SdcRxHwH2@o2ShlmlaQ9QlxHEsEY5LTHdxJ2zbJrYQMEUdipiLwdazLM/yPEs9qg6U1ewqi7ntawykiJzolsk/zPVu3uDVFN31nn38X2nZsjcO33z7ZLbkYQraEjRMr4cyI4rjtOlJgT4@ft2cIW28sNkSxmxcabr6li67m6Z475tvmv/3FhW6ct1IRnf5Cw)

### Explanation (outdated)

```java
s->{                                    // Lambda for Consumer<String>
 int l=99,                              //  Length of token, max is 99.
     X[][]=new int[10][l],              //  Array containing the occurrences per token
     d,                                 //  digit value
     D=0,                               //  digit holder for best sequence candidate
     m=0,                               //  holder of the current candidate
     M=0;                               //  best candidate for the current length of token.
 for(var x:s.split("(?<=(.))(?!\\1)"))  //  Tokenize the string into digit-repeating sequences
  X[x.charAt(0)-48][x.length()]++;      //   Add one occurrence for the token
 for(;M<1&&l-->1;)                      //  While no value has been found and for each length, descending. Do not decrease length if a value has been found.
  for(d=0;d++<9;)                       //   for each digit
   if((m=X[d][l])>1&m>M){               //    if the current occurrence count is at least 2 and that count is the current greatest for the length
    M=m;D=d;                            //     mark it as the current best
   }                                    //
 for(;l-->0;)System.out.print(D);       //  Output the best-fitting subsequence.
}                                       //
```

### Credits

- -9 bytes and bug spotting thanks to [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen)

Comment: I'm afraid there is a small flaw in your `j*o>M` check. If I understand correctly it takes the max `length * occurrence-count`. But for a test case like `1113311133933933933933` for example, the `111` would be (3 * 2 = 6), and the `33` would be (2 * 6 = 12). So it outputs `33` having the highest occurrence, instead of `111` being the longest occurring at least twice. Also, `var r="";for(;O-->0;)r+=D;return r;` can be golfed to `for(;O-->0;)System.out.print(D);` in Java 10, or even shorter in Java 11: `return(D+"").repeat(O);`.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I think I fixed it.

Comment: That indeed looks better, and nice way of golfing bytes at the same time. You just forgot to update your explanation. And you can golf 1 more byte changing `int X[][]=new int[10][99],d,l=99,` to `int l=99,X[][]=new int[10][l],d,`.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Thanks! I also golfed one more byte by writing `d++<9` instead of `++d<10`. Sorry for the rest: I'm rather tired today =_=

Answer (score 2):

### PCRE, 152 bytes

```
(\d)(?<!(?=\1)..)(?=(\1*)(?!\1).*(?!\1).\1\2(?!\1))(?!(?:(?=\2((\3?+)(\d)(\5*)))){1,592}?(?=\2\3.*(?!\5).\5\6(?!\5))(?:\1(?=\1*\4\5(\7?+\5)))*+(?!\1))\2
```

See it in action on: https://regex101.com/r/0U0dEp/1 (just look at the first match in each test case)

This is just for fun, since regex isn't a real programming language in and of itself, and the solution is limited :P

Because a zero-width group such as `(?:)+` only matches once and doesn't repeat indefinitely, and because PCRE internally makes copies of groups quantified with limits, I've had to use a magic number in there ("{1,592}"), which means we can only look up to 592 contiguous sets of digits ahead to find a competing set that could be longer than the one currently under inspection. More info on this concept [here](http://www.drregex.com/2017/11/lookahead-quantification-utterly-loopy.html).

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 88 bytes

```perl
my($m,%s);++$i%2*$s{$_}++&&($n=$s{$_}/9+length)>$m&&($a=$_,$m=$n)for pop=~/((.)\2*)/g;$a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZDfb5swEMff@StOyLQ40DLzo0AZbSrtpS/ry97GhNLWobQBvOBIq0L2r6dnpyXplrN8J999fPfVCb5cRNt@dQ/z9bZ5tUnjWj3NHIfUlj8h/ZqUG8c5ObFJm@9eXuoseFvJJ3pFGlWY5aR0SZOTls67JYhO5H892z6nhT@hXpWR2XZjNK8wlbyXeTMTPz27eHTo@eRax2JQEdFfbi8WtfSK1nOfu7o1Tffrt5sfN1eZgY1t/Z@uDQCls3annObVkgucPiVlpvNAqnyORaqeYlm3cg6mdXbRA4B15ocq8j@CP0j@iAn2RSWqToLVF63p4icAWzXFRsB/A/YGnAPXYN69mHAJ5neEuxfTBVQASqV9OpwqLZipMmNjGGWpRJelcduKlbwEiBNlUXiB5sdMBTUH7lZSAyoxwkEQMMZ2PsUL7/YBY2rfOI4R3Hk4sA8WKwOWRp752oIgPM4foAljcRzijRMWJP5/aDKSURSxCKcEGI81ZQfjA/8T8i85@CObhmEapmmoj46f2XCvVC9Xe9xj9H4PlCrba2BqCaM/tt4BS8b2DQ)

Slightly ungolfed, with tests:

```perl
sub f {
  my($m,%s);
  my($i,$n,$a);           #not needed in golfed version
  ++$i % 2  *  $s{$_}++
  && ($n=$s{$_}/9+length) > $m
  && ($a=$_, $m=$n)
    for pop=~/((.)\2*)/g; #i.e. 7888885466662716666 => 7 88888 5 4 6666 2 7 1 6666
  $a
}
for(map[/\d+/g],split/\n/,join"",<DATA>){ #tests
  my($i,@e)=@$_;
  printf "%-6s   input %-24s   expected %-10s   got %s\n",
    (grep f($i) eq $_, @e) ? "Ok" : "Not ok", $i, join('|',@e), f($i);
}
__DATA__
Input:  7888885466662716666     Output: 6666
Input:  3331113331119111        Output: 111
Input:  777333777333            Output: 777|333
Input:  122222233433            Output: 33
Input:  811774177781382         Output: 8
Input:  555153333551            Output: 1
Input:  12321                   Output: 1|2
Input:  944949949494999494      Output: 4
Input:  8888858888866656665666  Output: 88888
Input:  1112221112221111        Output: 111|222
```

Answer (score 1):

## Japt `-h`, 12 bytes

Input & output are strings.

```
ò¦ ñÊf@ÓZè¶X
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=8qYg8cpmQNNa6LZY&input=IjkxMTEzMzExMTMzOTMzOTMzOTMzOTMzOSIKLWg=)